# Validating a json with attribute named "type"

Tags: python, jsonschema

I'm trying to assert a json with the format:

```
{"type": "mystring", "data": "mystring2"}
```

By using this code:

```py
from jsonschema import validate

schema = {"type": "string", "data": "string"}
myjson = {"type": "mystring", "data": "mystring2"}

validate(myjson, schema)
```

And I'm getting this error:

```
jsonschema.exceptions.ValidationError: {'type': 'mystring', 'data': 'mystring2'} is not of type 'string'

Failed validating 'type' in schema:

    {'data': 'string', 'type': 'string'}

On instance:
    {'data': 'mystring2', 'type': 'mystring'}
```

It looks like the "type" attribute is reserved to assert the type of the document. 
If I change the "type" attribute (from both schema and myjson variables) for any other thing it works normally!

Is there any way to assert an attribute named "type" using jsonschema?

Comment: There we go.. yip, type cant by mystring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scheming the root object worked for me:

```py
from jsonschema import validate

schema = {
    'type': 'object',
    'properties': {
        'data': { 'type': 'string' },
        'type': { 'type': 'string' }
    }
}

myjson = {'type': 'mystring', 'data': 'mystring2'}

validate(myjson, schema) # All good
```

Now let's make it fail:

```py
myjson = {'type': 42, 'data': 'mystring2'}

validate(myjson, schema)

Failed validating 'type' in schema['properties']['type']:
    {'type': 'string'}

On instance['type']:
    42
```

Answer (score 1):

I have made a simpler version to illustrate the issue. Your type is set incorrectly.

```
from jsonschema import validate

schema = {"data": {"type" : "string"}} # define your key then its type
myjson = {"data": "mystring"} # your key, and its value

validate(myjson, schema) # validate
```

Using your own data

```
from jsonschema import validate

schema = { "data": {"type": "string"}}
myjson = {"type": "mystring", "data": "mystring2"}

validate(myjson, schema)
```

Reading the docs and playing with their example is always a good idea.

https://python-jsonschema.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately I think it does not solve the problem.


This works to assert this json: `{"data": "mystring"}`.

But the json I'm trying to assert is this: `{"type": "mystring", "data": "mystring2"}`

Comment: Recheck my answer. You are specifying it incorrectly, you have `type` then your string` mystring`, it should be `type` `string`. Then you pass in your data to calidate against the config/schmea. Your schema currenly has mystring as a type? Ive never heard of a mystring type. But a string type sure.